# how to create custom route in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

i am trying to like this (/User/Index?abc) url in after RedirectToAction
How to do it Please suggest me..

RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Putabc",
   url: "{tempUrl}/{RegNo}",
   defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Index", RegNo = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

Controller:-

```
public ActionResult Putabc() 
{ 
    string RegNo = "abc"; 
     string tempUrl = Url.Action("Index", "User");
    return RedirectToAction(new { url = tempUrl + "?{RegNo}" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

**Inside RouteConfig**

```
     routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

//Note:Here "Home" and "Index" are your default controller and action

**Controller**

```
 [RoutePrefix("User")]

public class SomeController : Controller
{  
 //This action will be hit by 

 // www.yoursite.com/User/Index?url=some
   public ActionResult Index(string url) 
   { 

   }  
}
```

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{ 
   public ActionResult Putabc() 
  { 
     string RegNo = "abc"; 
     string tempUrl = Url.Action("Index", "User");
      return RedirectToAction(new { url = tempUrl + "?{RegNo}" }, 
     JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }  
}
```